# where am i going wrong in my extraction of value from mysql database?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

where am i going wrong in my extraction of country name from mysql database? 
(codeigniter: activerecord enabled)
Its printing out "default country" instead of expected "Australia".

**Pages Controller**

```
public function view($page)
{

    $page = strtoupper($page); // Capitalize the first letter
    $data = array(
               'title' => 'My Title',
               'country' => 'default country'
          );




    $this->getCountryName($page, $data);

if(!is_null($data['country'])){
        $page = "country";  
    }

    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->helper('utility');
    $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('pages/'.$page, $data);

    if(!is_null($data['country'])){
    $this->load->view('templates/infobox', $data);  
    }

    $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);

}

function getCountryName(&$page, &$data){

    $this->db->select('name')->from('pv_country')->where('code', $page);


    $query = $this->db->get();



        if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
        {
           foreach ($query->result() as $row)
           {
              $data['country'] =  $row;
              echo $row;
           }
        }   

    }
```

**Country View**

```
<div style =" position:absolute;top:90%; background: red;">
<?php echo $country; ?></div> // prints default country.
</div>
```

[image: country codes]

> A PHP Error was encountered
> Severity: 4096
> Message: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string
> Filename: pages/country.php
> Line Number: 25

Comment: Is the context of `$data` before its sent to the template correct?

Comment: not sure i understand bartek? default country i set when array is initialised. but i try to set country to value from database when i call the function getCountryName by reference. I am now getting an error, will update with it.

Comment: sorry for the trying question Bartek, but im finding the docs abit confusing in some points. Its probably because im still new to PHP and CI docs assume some exp with it already. i worked it out tho, please vote back up if you will, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so i put in some more debugging and found the correct syntax/method to call to get the result,
which then returns an object with attributes that need to be accessed in the view.

```
function getCountryName(&$page, &$data){

    $this->db->select('name')->from('pv_country')->where('code', $page);
    $query = $this->db->get();

        if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
        {

          $data['country'] =  $query->row();    

        }   
}
```

[image]

```
<?php echo $country->name; ?>
```

Comment: Hooray, you got it! Sorry I could not be more help. Sometimes the only answer is just more debugging :)